# Show that a set S is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this assingment:

Show that $ S = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3} | A^T = -A\} $ is a subspace in $ \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3} $

How do I do that?

In the answer is says just: $$ 0\in S, then \; O^T=0=-0 $$ Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Do you know the standard method for showing that something is a subspace?

Comment: I think that I am supposed to prove that scalar multiplication and addition holds, right?

Comment: You are supposed to prove the set is closed under addition and under scalar multiplication (and also that the set is not empty). So; how would you go about showing that the set is closed under addition?

Comment: If "the" answer *really* says that only, then it is dead wrong. Read the other comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw now that the solution I wrote above just proves that the axiom for zero holds... that was not the whole solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not all you need. For a set $S$ to be a subspace, you need to prove that for any two elements $A,B\in S$ and any scalar $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, the element $A+\beta B$ is an element of the same set $S$.

In your example, take $A$ and $B$ from $S$ (this means that $A^T=-A$ and $B^T=-B$) and $\alpha$ from $\mathbb R$. Now, can you prove that $A+\alpha B\in S$? For this, you must show that $(A+B)^T = -(A+B)$. Can you show this?

Comment: And how do I prove that? I could prove it easily for some specific A, b and $\alpha$ but how do I do it generally for all values?

Comment: Use rules you know about transposition. For example, $(A+B)^T$ can be rewritten in some other way.

Comment: Ok, I almost get it now. Why do you set $A^T$ to -1?

Comment: Just a typo, I fixed it. thank you.

Comment: Oh! So the definition I wrote in the question states that for any variable A, $A^T=-A$? I did not really get that in the beginning... I think I can solve it now.. Thanks!

Comment: Well, for any matrix $A\in S$, yes, you have $A^T=-A$. In fact, any time you have a set writen as $S=\{x| P(x)\}$ where $P$ is some contition (in your case $x^T=-x$), this means that the elements of $S$ are EXACTLY those values $x$ for which $P(x)$ holds.